# Calling function defined in the different block (Red/Rebol)

Tags: rebol, red

I am trying to figure out how to call a function defined like this:

```
outer: [inner: [ f: func [p1 p2] [rejoin ["p1:" p1 "/p2:" p2]] ]]

print outer/inner/f "aaa" "bbb"
```

> func

If I add `do` infront of the function call, I get

> *** Script Error: func is missing its spec argument

Could someone point out what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is `block!` of data. Data do not turn to code until they are evaluated. You probably want to turn that `block!` into an `object!`. Try this:

```
>> outer: object [inner: object [ f: func [p1 p2] [rejoin ["p1:" p1 "/p2:" p2]] ]]
== make object! [
    inner: make object! [
        f: func [p1 p2][rejoin ["p1:" p1 "/p2:" p2]]
    ]
]
>> print outer/inner/f "aaa" "bbb"
p1:aaa/p2:bbb
```

Answer (score 3):

In Rebol blocks are not evaluated by default (e.g. `do [...]` or `if true [...]`). In your example, `outer/inner/f` is returning the unevaluated word `'func`. If you wish for a function to be placed in such a way, you'll need to choose a way to create it, such as:

```
outer: compose/deep [inner: [f: (func [p1 p2][...])]]
```

Or:

```
outer: [inner: [f: none]]
outer/inner/f: func [p1 p2][...]
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an explanation and alternative implementation, but in my case I think object is a more natural way to express the intent.

Comment: @aseidlitz I suspected so—can never be sure though with Rebol... :)